# Add a new field to every document from my mongo DB collection via mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose

This question was asked several times, but despite that, I wasn't able to solve my problem. In my mongoose collection, I store 30 users with the following mongoose schema. I want to implement a newsletter on my site, therefore I want to add the new field:

```
  newsletter: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: true
  },
```

My question is: How can I add newsletter false/true to every user?
I found that, but it didn't work.

```
User.updateMany({}, [{ $set: { newsletter: false }}])
```

**My Schema:**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
 
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({   
    name: { type: String, required: true },   
    email: { type: String, required: true },   
    password: { type: String, required: true },   
    date: { type: Date, default: Date.now },   
    token: { type: String, required: true } 
});
 
const User = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
 
module.exports = User;
```

Adding to the schema "newsletter" does solve the problem for new users, but doesn't add the field to the already existing ones.

Comment: `User.updateMany({}, [{ $set: { newsletter: false}}])` seems ok but its pipeline update, so you have to check that you have mongodb 4.2+, and to see if that driver method accept a update pipeline as argument

Comment: `'false'` - thats a _string_, not a _Boolean_ value.

Comment: So I checked my versions: Mongo DB: 5.0.6,  mongoose: 6.1.7.

Comment: I changed 'false' in false. Thanks!